# Flutter Unhandled Exception: type 'UserModel' is not a subtype of type 'List<Product>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm, viewmodel

this is the JSON Response i got from Postman

```
{
"error": false,
"products": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "newproduct2",
    }
],
"units": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ml",
    }
]
```

}

when i convert json response to model class

```
import 'dart:convert';

UserModel userListModelFromJson(String str) =>
    UserModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userListModelToJson(UserModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UserModel {
  bool error;
  List<Product> products;
  List<Unit> units;

  UserModel({
    required this.error,
    required this.products,
    required this.units,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
        error: json["error"],
        products: List<Product>.from(
            json["products"].map((x) => Product.fromJson(x))),
        units: List<Unit>.from(json["units"].map((x) => Unit.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "error": error,
        "products": List<dynamic>.from(products.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "units": List<dynamic>.from(units.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Product {
  int id;
  String name;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.name
  });

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"]
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name
      };
}

class Unit {
  int id;
  String name;

  Unit({
    required this.id,
    required this.name
  });

  factory Unit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Unit(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"]
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name
      };
}
```

Finally i have an viewmodel to network call

```
    class UsersViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _loading = false;
  UserModel _userListModel = {} as UserModel;
  late UserError _userError;

  bool get loading => _loading;
  UserModel get userListModel => _userListModel;
  UserError get userNewError => _userError;

  UsersViewModel() {
    getUsers();
  }
  setLoading(bool loading) async {
    _loading = loading;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  setUserListModel(UserModel userListModel) {
    _userListModel = userListModel;
  }

  setUserError(UserError userError) {
    _userError = userError;
  }

  getUsers() async {
    setLoading(true);
    var response = await UserServices.getUsers();
    if (response is Success) {
      print(response.response);
      setUserListModel(response.response as UserModel);
    }
    if (response is Failure) {
      UserError userError = UserError(
          errorCode: response.code, message: response.errorResponse.toString());
      print(response.errorResponse.toString());
      setUserError(userError);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }
}
```

Where i need only list of products

UserService Class :

```
    import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:my_first_project/user_list/models/users_list_model.dart';
import 'package:my_first_project/user_list/repo/api_status.dart';
import 'package:my_first_project/user_list/utils/constants.dart';

class UserServices {
  static Future<Object> getUsers() async {
    try {
      var url = Uri.parse(USERS_LIST);
      var response = await http.get(url);
      if (200 == response.statusCode) {
        return Success(
            response: userListModelFromJson(response.body), code: 200);
      }
      return Failure(
          code: USER_INVALID_RESPONSE, errorResponse: "Invalid Response");
    } on HttpException {
      return Failure(code: NO_INTERNET, errorResponse: "no Internet");
    } on FormatException {
      return Failure(code: INVALID_FORMAT, errorResponse: "Invalid Format");
    } catch (e) {
      return Failure(code: UNKNOWN_ERROR, errorResponse: "Unknown Error");
    }
  }
}
```

but when i run this code i got an error of

**E/flutter (29438): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'UserModel' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast**

Comment: show your `UserServices` class

Comment: had updated my UserService class please check @Alann Maulana

Answer (score 0):

In `UserServices`, your Success.response is of type `UserModel`.

```dart
if (200 == response.statusCode) {
        return Success(
            response: userListModelFromJson(response.body), code: 200);
      }
UserModel userListModelFromJson(String str) =>· UserModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));
```

However, in the `getUsers()` method of `UsersViewModel`, you are explicitly casting `success.response` to the type `List<Product>`.

```dart
if (response is Success) {
      print(response.response);
      setUserListModel(response.response as List<Product>);
    }
```

success.response is of type UserModel, not List

Comment: after updating viewmodel . i got an error 

type '_Map<dynamic, dynamic> is not a subtype of type 'UserModel' in type cast ' @choykari

Comment: https://dartpad.dev/?id=c0f7c578204d61e08ec0fbc4d63456cd

This is a dartpad that simplifies your code, and you can run it.

The only change I made was to modify the json you provided, I removed the commas after "newproduct2" and "ml" or the json parsing would fail. @SasidharanIOS

Comment: even after i removed the comma, i got the same error in ui itself @choykari

Comment: Do you still have errors running dartpad, that's your code. @SasidharanIOS